# Use xargs input in eval command

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a file "commands.php" that dynamically generates bash commands. For example, one line is:

```
# - commands.php
ssh me@123.123.123.123 echo "text" > file; reboot;
```

How can I use the output of `xargs` to execute these commands... eval, maybe?

```
cat commands.php | xargs -L 1 -I {} 'eval "$({})"';
```

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. Why would you want to do this? What's wrong with `bash /path/to/file`?

Comment: Hi Patrick, very well could be! I have a file that dynamically generates bash commands, and it is not a `.sh` file. (I could copy the output to an sh file, but am interested in how to execute each line of a non-sh file

Comment: Everything else aside,  is this php script actually. Allen from the web? This seems very risky.

Comment: @mattdm haha good catch! but yes this is a very secure environment, not some public external file.

Answer (score 10):

Figured out a way:

```
cat commands.php | xargs -L 1 -I {} sh -c "{}"
```

runs each command out of shell... simple enough!

Comment: Why do you insist on `cat`ing the file? A simple redirection would be enough: `xargs ... <commands.php`

Comment: And if you want to do it in parallel, use GNU Parallel: cat commands.php | parallel

Answer (score 2):

If your PHP file outputs shell commands, you could probably get away with

```
$( php /path/to/your/script.php )
```

Or

```
while read line; do
    $line
done < $( php /path/to/your/script.php )
```